# textbox with arabic language

Tags: c#, textbox, arabic

I have a problem with a textbox. the problem is that I initialized the property

```
textBox1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```

and when I typed arabic characters it types correctly but the problem if I type the following
string

> 66/ج ح /
>
> 96

the number 96 after the / but the editor doesn't allow to write it that way so when I read it it change its characters like this :

> ج ح/66/96

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms textbox, ASP.NET, or what other kind?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var LRM = ((char)0x200E).ToString();
 lbldate.Text = ddlTrnNoYears.SelectedItem.Text+'/' + LRM + ddlTrainingMonth.SelectedItem.Text + LRM +'/'+ddlTrainingDay.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Result :

```
۳۹۹/‎مرحبا‎/۳
```